# ArithmeticException divide by zero

Tags: java

I am trying to answer Project Euler problem number 53. I am taking a rather brute force approach, but it seems to me that my logic should come up with the right answer, even if it takes awhile.So what is it that I am doing wrong in this situation besides it being rather inefficient, that is making the compiler come back with an ArithmeticException divide by zero.

```
import java.util.*;

public class problem53 
{
  public static int fact(int x)
  {
    int total = 0;
    if(x != 0)
    {
      for(int i=(x-1);i>0;i--)
      {
        x = x*i;
        total = x;
      }
    }
    if(x==0)
      total = 1;
    return total;
  }

  public static int combo(int y,int z)
  {
      int end = 0;
      if(y==0)
        y=2;
      if(z==0)
        z=1;
      if(y-z != 0)
      {
        end = fact(y)/(fact(z)*(fact(y-z)));
      }
      return end;
 }

public static void main(String[]args)
{
  int answer = 0;
  List<Integer> sure = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  for(int i=20;i<=100;i++)
  {
    for(int j=2;j<i;j++)
    {
      int ferNow = combo(i,j);
      if(ferNow>=1000000)
        sure.add(ferNow);
    }
  }
  answer = sure.size();
  System.out.println(answer);
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Your `fact()` is broken. It will return `0` for `fact(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

if  **z =1 or y-z =1** you will receive a this error

Because fact(1) return 0

Comment: Okay, but why? What part of the method makes t return 0? I've added a lot in there, needless to say, and if I can get that method to not return 0 for 1 then I can clean it up considerably.